# Android send latitude and longitude on an interval, Location Object

Tags: android, gps, location, locationmanager, locationlistener

I've looked at a few other questions and tutorials but I'm not getting what I'm looking for

I am trying to get the latitude and longitude in this format

latitude = 40.769134 , longitude = -73.960905

I implemented this class which takes my global variables latitude and longitude (they are long data types)

```
 class GpsListener implements LocationListener{

        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              latitude = location.getLatitude();
              longitude = location.getLongitude();
              //float speed = location.getSpeed();
              checkin();

        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

}
```

I've looked at other tutorials here and notice that people use the `LocationManager` class to interface with my `LocationListener` but all I really need to do is use a `Location` object becuase my class `GpsListener.onLocationChanged(..  )` needs a location object, but can you give an example or guidance on how to use the location object or how to simply get this longitude and latitude?

I am simply passing the latitude and longitude to a server so I dont need to do anything else with the GPS module, my `checkin()` function makes the server call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you trying to avoid using the LocaitonManager?

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,new MyLocationListener());
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

if you just want to use it once, I suppose you could deregister everything after receiving a location.  But maybe you want to make sure the accuracy is within x meters etc..

Comment: I don't want to avoid using it, I just don't know how to use it to get the result I need. I simply need the current longitude and latitude in my long format. LocationManager and LocationListener don't seem to give me the control I'm looking for (or I dont understand it). I need a Location Object

Comment: I have a GPS app that will route locations.. and I just browsed over it and getting the location is pretty much as simple as the listener you have + implementation of the location manager.  You're not trying to get the GPS coordinates via the emulator are you?  If so you have to feed it GPS coordinates via the DDMS or you can use the terminal window.  Also don't forget you need to use the correct permissions in the manifest.

Comment: hey, everything worked like it should, the phone I was using was not working like it should. I ran my original code (very similar to yours) and the GPS indicator blinked and the server got my coordinates just fine!

Comment: glad to here it .. best of luck